# Is it possible to use redux-form without using connect()?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, connect, redux-form

For various reasons that are not my call, in my work application, we are using `redux` without the connect `HOC`. There are pros and cons here.  But is it possible to use `redux-form` in this manner, currently I have `redux-form1 using it's own store via`connect()`, which means it's less than ideal, there is at times state being passed between the two stores, the single source of truth is lost.

*Is* there any way I can use `redux-form` without using the connect `HOC`?

Comment: Please add related code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the react-redux `connect` HOC to use redux form. Redux form provides its own connect-like HOC called [`reduxForm`](http://redux-form.com/7.0.3/docs/api/ReduxForm.md/). Wrap your form components with it using the config described in the link above, and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Redux forms uses `reduxForm` instead of connect, Here is an example.

```
NewCampaignForm.propTypes = {
  fields: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  handleSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  resetForm: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  submitting: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'new-campaign-form',
  fields
})(NewCampaignForm);
```

And if you did want to, you could use `connect` on the parent container of that form, and it would work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **reduxForm HOC**. If you are using

> **semantic-ui-react**,

then u can wrap fields by using **`<Form.Field>`**